# Using this.property in local function does not make changes to the property

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to write a basic function in order to produce a cash machine.  Whenever I run the below code, I get the total staying at 0.  Can anyone help me out or explain to me why?

```
function VirtualCashMachine(){

    //object storing food
    this.food = {egg: 0.98, milk: 1.23, magazine: 4.99,chocolate: 0.45};

    //total bill
    this.total = 0;
    //record of last transaction
    this.lastTransactionAmount = 0;

    //assign public methods
    this.scan = scan;
    this.voidLastTransaction = voidLastTransaction;       

    //define public methods    

    //add amount to total property
    function scan(/*string*/item,/*integer*/ quantity){

        //if food item exists in food object, find price and calculate total
        if(this.food.hasOwnProperty(item)){

            cost = this.food[item] * quantity;
            add(cost);
            this.lastTransactionAmount = cost;

        }
    };

    function voidLastTransaction(){
        this.total -= lastTransactionAmount; 
    };

    //define private method

    //add item price to total
    function add(itemCost){
         this.total = this.total + itemCost; 
    };
}

var VCM = new VirtualCashMachine();
VCM.scan("egg", 3);


console.log(VCM.total);
```

The problem seems to arise when I implemented the add function.  My reasoning is that once I find the total costs for 3 eggs in this example, I add the amount to the `this.total` and can repeat this for other sorts of food.

Answer (score 3):

Re-write add to be a property of this:

```
this.add = function (itemCost) {
  this.total = this.total + itemCost; 
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but you probably don't want to expose the `add` function to outsiders. I think the OP wants to keep it private to the constructor's scope.

Comment: You're right, makes sense. Alexei's answer is a far better solution.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. What's the point of making a method private if data is not private?

Comment: Yeah, that's also true.

Answer (score 3):

"this" is often not what you think it is... I.e. when you call function without context (`add` instead of `VCM.scan`) the context will be set to global object. There are many articles on the subject - i.e. [Understanding JavaScript Context](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html).

There are several options to deal with it.

One is to call it with context by making it "public member" as suggested by tomca32 (Note that it will expose private methods which may not be desirable in many cases):

this.add = function(itemCost) { this.total += itemCost;}
   this.add(cost);

Another option is to save `this` into local variable so you know what exactly you are using:

```
function VirtualCashMachine(){
   var self = this;
   ....
   function add(itemCost){
     self.total = self.total + itemCost; 
};
```

Or you can explicitly pass context with `function.call`:

```
function add(itemCost) { this.total += itemCost;}
add.call(this, cost);
```

or you can avoid `this` in local functions altogether, but you'll need to expose properties with get/set methods. In this case since function will sees all local variables in parent's scope it can correctly modify total:

```
var total = 0;
this.getTotal() { return total;} 
function add(itemCost) { total += itemCost;}
```

Second approach (with copying `this` to local variable) is quite common and easiest to follow in my opinion: simply use `self` (or other commonly used `me` or `that`) everywhere inside your class where you would use `this.`.

Comment: I've tried this out and it works, cheers!  Can someone explain to me why this works?

Comment: Simply put, when you call `add` with just `add(...)`, you don't specify anything for the `this` context. That means that the `this` context is bound to the global scope (the `window` object), meaning that you're writing to the global variable `total` instead. You need to explicitly specify the this context using `this.add(...)` (if `add` is a property of `VirtualCashMachine`) or using `add.call(this, ...)`. Alternatively, you don't rely on this at all and use a local variable to hold the correct context (i.e. `self`). I recommend reading up about `this` in JavaScript.

Comment: @user2784840 - I've added couple more options (`call` and tomca32 +1 suggestion for `this.add`) + link to explanation.

Comment: If you have enough time, [this article](http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/), written by Mike West is excellent!